# Disable UAC And Windows Security Center alerts under Vista Business

Tags: security, windows-vista, uac

We have a few Windows Vista Business with User Account Control turned off (the reason is because those machines need to run a series of programs that do not work with UAC, the boxes have no Internet connectivity so this is not a security problem). But I'd like to know if there's a way to disable the annoying "popup" that appears every time they boot the machine. I know that Antivirus and other stuff has the "Not Monitored" flag in the Windows Security Center, but this doesn't seem to be present for UAC.

The users keep complaining about that and I was wondering if there was a "registry hack" or similar to turn that off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UAC warning is set by a registry key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{FD6905CE-952F-41F1-9A6F-135D9C6622CC}

You can disable this warning by deleting or disabling this key. Usual warnings about editing the registry apply.

Comment: "Usual warnings about editing the registry apply." -> Loved that one. Thanks.

Comment: I agree! That sentence should be a web classic in a few weeks:)